# Exercise on first and second order derivative in sense of distributions.

Tags: analysis, weak-derivatives

I need some help on this problem. I have to fins the first and second order derivative in sense of distributions of:

$$v(x)=\operatorname{sign}\cos(\pi x)$$

where the function sign is equal to $1$ if $x\ge0$ or to $-1$ if $x<0$.

So I think I have some step from $-1$ to $1$ oscillating like cosine.

I've tried to apply the definition but I have a lot of doubt about it. Could someone help me to well understand this topic? Thank you very much! :).

Comment: On the left side you have a function of $t$ and on the right side you have a function of $x.$ I will assume that's a typo.

Comment: Corrected! Thank you :).